# How to Live Update Ember Model with Search Results from API

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Quick backgorund: I am creating a recipe app with Ember frontend and a Rails API backend. I am implementing a search feature to find recipes based on ingredients. I have already configured my Rails API endpoint which sends back the correct records. My problem now is that I am having a very difficult time live updating my results, ie. the model data is not updating the template. This seems like a trivial problem, but for whatever reason I haven't been able to figure it out.

Here is what my project looks like:

```
model(params) {
    this.store.query('recipe', {query: params}).then( response => {
        console.log("RESPONSE", response);
    })
}
```

recipes index.hbs (this does not currently update):

```
{{recipe-card-container recipes=model}}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: What do you mean it's not updating? When you're creating a new instance of a recipe?

Comment: I think it has something to do with this: http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/models/frequently-asked-questions/

Comment: Essentially, I am getting the records from my API (which i can verify with console log), but these are not being made available from my model in the template

Answer (score 0):

Well, I feel stupid. Forgot a return before this.store.query -__-

Answer (score 0):

You not only forgot the `return`, but you also are failing to set the model correctly due to your debugging statement. Should be:

```
model(params) {
    var result = this.store.query('recipe', {query: params});
    result.then(response => console.log("RESPONSE", response));
    return result;
}
```

With your code, even after adding a return, the return value from `model` will be a promise which resolves to the value of the function printing out the response, which is undefined.